# Trying to learn WSDL and getting this "simple" SOAP JavaScript client to work

Tags: javascript, wsdl

I was looking an old thread over 5 years ago asking for the most simplest SOAP code using Javascript.

This was the most highest rated comment and marked as answered:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soap() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://somesoapurl.com/', true);

            // build SOAP request
            var sr =
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<soapenv:Envelope ' + 
                    'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                    'xmlns:api="http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API" ' +
                    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                    'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                    '<soapenv:Body>' +
                        '<api:some_api_call soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
                            '<username xsi:type="xsd:string">login_username</username>' +
                            '<password xsi:type="xsd:string">password</password>' +
                        '</api:some_api_call>' +
                    '</soapenv:Body>' +
                '</soapenv:Envelope>';

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
                    }
                }
            }
            // Send the POST request
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            xmlhttp.send(sr);
            // send request
            // ...
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<html>
```

I've tried to copy and paste it into a .html to get it running so I can see how it works, but it still doesn't work. In line-7 of the code, I replaced

```
https://somesoapurl.com/
```

with an actual free WSDL URL I found from searching on Google:

```
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL
```

When I click on the "Soap" button and look at the console to see the code run, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 405.

Can someone assist? I want to get this SOAP client call using JavaScript working so I can understand WSDL and SOAP better.